# Magento 1.7 : Admin - Custom Customer Grid attribute - not filterable

Tags: magento, attributes, admin

I'm not sure why, but I can't filter my attribute (it works fine with defaults ones).

Here is my code :

Config.xml

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <customer_grid>SaponeWebConcept_PrivateSells_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid</customer_grid>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

Grid.php

```
public function setCollection($collection)
{
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('wants_to_be_vip');                    
    parent::setCollection($collection);
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    parent::_prepareColumns();
    $attributeCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
    ->setCodeFilter('wants_to_be_vip')
    ->getFirstItem();
    $itemsOptions = $attributeCollection->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
    $optionsArr = array();
    foreach ($itemsOptions as $option) {
        $optionsArr[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
    }

    $this->addColumn('V.I.P', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('customer')->__('Veut devenir V.I.P'),
        'index' => 'wants_to_be_vip',
        'type'  => 'options',
        'options' => $optionsArr,
    ));
    $this->addColumnsOrder('customer_id','wants_to_be_vip');
}
```

Thanks for you help !

Edit : It may need some more infos :
- Values display ok.
- My select box is ok too.
- When I press the filter button, it loads, and nothing changes.

Comment: I'm not pretty sure that. 'filter' => true, this key value can add your VIP Col.

Comment: Filter is induced with `options` type, and otherwise must either be a class name or `false` if filtering must be disabled.

Comment: @user1745154 Do you actually need the specific renderer that is currently applied to the column (`SaponeWebConcept_PrivateSells_Adminhtml_Block_Render_Confirmation`) ? Can you test the filtering without it ?

Comment: @ Thiha : Yes, filter => true seems useless :).
@ blmage : Thanks, I don't really need my renderer anymore.
But even witouth it, it's still not working :(

Comment: Can it be due to something else ? I cleared the cache (which is disabled), Compiling is disabled too.